# Bash: filling 2d Array - strange behaviour

Tags: arrays, bash

At first I declare an array with **declare -a matrix** and do not initialize any values.
Then I print the values of the array in the following way:
if a value of the matrix on the particular position equals 1 it should print 1, else it should print _

So without setting any values I get the predictable output.

But if I for example do: **matrix[10,10]=1** and I print the array, suddenly always on the position **matrix[x,10]** the value is always 1.

Why does it behave like this?
What do I have to do if I only want to initialize some particular positions with 1 and not all the others in the same row?

```
#!/bin/bash
#read N
declare -a matrix

for (( i=0; i<10; i++));do
    for (( j=0; j<20; j++));do
        if [[ matrix[$i,$j] -eq 1 ]];then
            printf 1
        else
            printf _
        fi
    done
    echo
done

echo

matrix[10,10]=1

for (( i=0; i<10; i++));do
    for (( j=0; j<20; j++));do
        if [[ matrix[$i,$j] -eq 1 ]];then
            printf 1
        else
            printf _
        fi
    done
    echo
done
```

thats the output:

```
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________

__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
__________1_________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 2D arrays in Bash.

The stuff inside `[..]` is arithmetically evaluated. `,` there is a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The result is the second value. `matrix[10,10]=1` is the same as `matrix[1,2,3,4,5,etc,10]=1` is the same as `matrix[10]=1`.

You can use associative arrays, in which case the stuff inside `[...]` is a *string*, in which case `,` will be a character. `declare -A matrix`. Note that your loop `(( i=0; i<10; i++))` never goes to `10`.

Comment: Also `matrix[$i,$j]` should be `${matrix[$i,$j]}`.